# Pause video on bootstrap carousel slide change

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog, carousel

I have an array of videos which are displayed by Bootstrap carousel embedded in a modal dialog box. The video doesn't start playing automatically when the modal is show but you need to click on it and it will start playing. My issues is that on slide change the current video playing won't pause. So this is what i need to achieve, to pause current video when the user changes slides(back or forth). How can I do this?
BTW I am using React Js.

Any help is greatly valued.Thanks.✌️

**Below is my Video Carousel component.**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Carousel from 'react-bootstrap/Carousel';
import "../carousel.css";

export default class VideoCarousel extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.videoRef = React.createRef();
    // this.state = {
    //   index: 0,
    //   isPlaying: false
    // }
  }
render(){
return(
      <div>
      <Carousel activeIndex={this.index} onSelect={this.handleChange} interval={null}  className="carousel">
          {this.props.items.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                  <Carousel.Item key={index}>
                  <video 
                    ref = {this.videoRef} 
                    className="videoItem" 
                    controls="controls"
                  >
                    <source src={item.src} type="video/mp4"/>
                  </video>
                  <Carousel.Caption>
                    {/* <h2>{item.title}</h2> */}
                  </Carousel.Caption>
                  </Carousel.Item>
              );
          })}
      </Carousel>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Problem

You are using the same reference for all the items. After running the map function this.videoRef will be equal to the last element of the array.

#### Solution 1: keep the references in an array

Create the ref initialized by an empty array:

```
 this.videoRef = React.createRef([]);
```

Iterate over the elements and assign the reference based on the index value:

```
<Carousel activeIndex={this.index} onSelect={this.handleChange} interval={null}  className="carousel">
  {this.props.items.map((item, index) => {
     return (
          <Carousel.Item key={index}>
            <video 
              ref = {el => this.videoRef.current[index] = el} 
              ...
            >
              ... 
          </Carousel.Item>)
   })}
</Carousel>
```

To pause the video use the element reference at specific position:

```
this.videoRef.current[index].pause();
```

#### Solution 2: Create a component for the carrousel item

You can handle the controls functions on componentDidMount/componentWillUnmount

```
 this.videoRef = React.createRef(null);
```

Assign the reference:

```
export default class VideoCarouselItem extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.videoRef = React.createRef();
  }
 render(){
    <Carousel.Item key={this.props.key}>
       <video 
         ref = {this.videoRef} 
         ...
       >             
    </Carousel.Item>
 }
}
```

Then through properties pass the info you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I still can't find a way to do this. I get this error when I click on the Videos Button where the Video Carousel is supposed to appear on the screen.     "TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
VideoCarousel.handleChange
src/components/VideoCarousel.js:19
  16 |   console.log("indexx::", index);
> 19 |   this.videoRef.current[index].pause();
     | ^  20 |   
  21 | });
  22 | "    I'm not sure where I go wrong. Would you be able to help me with a fiddle? Many thanks. anyway.

Comment: Or this error: "TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of null
ref
src/components/VideoCarousel.js:34
  31 | <Carousel.Item key={index}>
  32 | <video 
  33 |   // ref = {this.videoRef.current[index]} 
> 34 |   ref = {el => this.videoRef.current[index] = el}  
     | ^  35 |   className="videoItem" 
  36 |   controls="controls"
  37 | > "

Comment: @AnadDana I updated my answer with another solution.